# Transform XML with multiple XSL files using <X:Transform> in a JSP

Tags: xml, jsp, xslt

How can i transform a XML file with multiple XSL  using  in a JSP.The below snipet represents Transformation using single Xsl.

```
 <x:transform xml  = "${inputDoc}" xslt = "${stylesheet}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store an intermediate result into a variable and feed the variable into the next transformation:

```
<x:transform xml="${inputDoc}" xslt="${stylesheet1}" var="temp"/>
<x:transform xml="${temp}" xslt="${stylesheet2}"/>
```